# Deputy not awarded

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, helpful-flags

I have 80 helpful flags. The last flag was more than 24 hours ago declared helpful. But I still did not get the badge!

This is servere!

[image: profile]
[image: badges]

[image: flagging history]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your "recommend close" flags weren't being tallied in the badge code - this has been fixed and will be rolled out shortly.